# Visual Studio: get EAX value at stepout?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

So I'm going to debug some outdated C++ application (built with mingw32); and I have no debug info / symbols / source for that.

I need to set a breakpoint at `WSAConnect` and get the returned value logged.

So, step-by-step execution allows me to see return value (like `0x2733` == `10035`, Winsock's "would not block" response); but at the moment of returning from function its always 0xFFFFFFFF, so I need a better way of logging register contents before the moment of return.

What Visual Studio's debugger has for that?

Comment: [`WSAConnect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741559) is supposed to return either zero or `SOCKET_ERROR`. And you are seeing the latter in `EAX`. To get the error code the caller is supposed to use `WSAGetLastError` or `GetLastError`. Visual Studio debugger does not do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just enter `eax` in the watch window of the debugger?